# Trailing windows after installing gnome shell!

Tags: gnome, 13.04, graphics

I am running 13.04 on this computer, and was interested in installing the gnome shell alongside unity. I followed the instructions on this link: http://www.itworld.com/software/358052/install-gnome-shell-38-ubuntu-1304

The gnome shell started working fine, but when i switched back to unity once to check on some printer driver problem, i encountered this graphic problem:

[image: My Desktop Problem]

Everything you do on the desktop kind of gets "imprinted" on it, even after you've closed the window! Moreover, when you drag a window, the entire trail remains. I didn't know where to classify this problem, or how to search for a similar problem, so i posted a new question.

Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing:

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell gnome-shell-extensions gnome-tweak-tool
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Restart you computer. And now, if you want Gnome Shell back, just install it from the *official* repositories (no need to add nonofficial repositories):

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell gnome-shell-extensions gnome-tweak-tool
```

If this does not solve it, try remembering if you tweaked something with Gnome Tweak Tool and add that to your question.

---

**[Edit]**

Try

```
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install --fix-broken
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center-unity
```

in Appearance change your theme from Adwaita to Ambiance. If this goes fine you should be able to install Gnome Shell from the official repository.

Comment: I tried this, and i successfully removed gnome-shell, but when i try to install it again from the official repositories, using the command you specified, it ends up with many unmet dependencies. What should i do?

Comment: When I try to input the command that you wrote, i get the following error:


'Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-shell : Depends: gdm (>= 3.5.90) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.'

Comment: New Development :/ After i ran the above commands, the Appearance button in the Settings window has disappeared. I discovered it when i tried to click on "Change Desktop Background", and instead of opening the Appearance window, it only opened the Settings window. Please help!

Comment: I did what you said, and at the end of all three commands, ubuntu seemed hunky-dory! It updates cleanly, didn't find anything worth fixing, and it already had the latest version of gnome-control-center-unity running. But at the end of this, i still cannot change any Appearance settings, because it seems to have been mysteriously removed from my PC :/ Any ideas? :(

Comment: Reinstall `gnome-control-center-unity` with `sudo apt-get purge gnome-control-center-unity && sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center-unity`.